# Tikz mindmap: combine "grow cyclic" with "clockwise from"

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps, tikz-graphs

I'd like to define a mindmap in tikz that basically do the same thing as `grow cyclic`, except that the direction of the first layer should go to the bottom instead of the right. I tried to use `clockwise from` to change the direction of the first layer, but it breaks everything... Note that the other layers should still grow "symetrically".

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=white, grow cyclic]
    node[concept] {Computer Science}
    child[concept color=green!50!black] {
      node[concept] {practical}
      child { node[concept] {algorithms} }
      child { node[concept] {data structures} }
      child { node[concept] {pro\-gramming languages} }
      child { node[concept] {software engineer\-ing} }
    }  
    child[concept color=blue] {
      node[concept] {applied}
      child { node[concept] {databases} }
      child { node[concept] {WWW} }
    }
    child[concept color=red] { node[concept] {technical} }
    child[concept color=orange] { node[concept] {theoretical} };
\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}
```

What I see:

[image]

What I want: the same thing, but everything rotated by 90 degrees clockwise, except the text of course that should still be readable without turning the head!

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to rotate by -90 degrees? Just tell it to Ti*k*Z.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=-90]
  \path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=white, grow cyclic]
    node[concept] {Computer Science}
    child[concept color=green!50!black] {
      node[concept] {practical}
      child { node[concept] {algorithms} }
      child { node[concept] {data structures} }
      child { node[concept] {pro\-gramming languages} }
      child { node[concept] {software engineer\-ing} }
    }  
    child[concept color=blue] {
      node[concept] {applied}
      child { node[concept] {databases} }
      child { node[concept] {WWW} }
    }
    child[concept color=red] { node[concept] {technical} }
    child[concept color=orange] { node[concept] {theoretical} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. To the OP, it works because `rotate` (and `scale`, etc.) are *not* applied to nodes by default (you have to use `transform shape` for that).